# Node.JS error code meanings? (Specifically fs)

Tags: node.js, debugging

Does anyone know what all of the error codes mean for Node.js, particularly the fs package?

I've looked all over, and can't find any documentation that gives me a list of error codes and their meanings.

Comment: It looks like fs is a series of simple wrappers around POSIX file functions. As such, I would think you should be able to check out the [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/toc.htm) api for exceptions relative to the file functions you're using.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's some links that should help. Not sure there's a single page out there that has this information catalogued clearly.

- [uv.h](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/3d3d48d4b78d48e9b002660fc045ba8bb4a96af2/deps/uv/include/uv.h#L65) defines most (all?) of them with a brief description. I think this is the best link I found in my brief github search.
- [uv-errno.h lists most of the UV error codes](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/a0a180a0adba6be3c567cd89e4bbca3561893e0d/deps/uv/include/uv-errno.h#L27). libuv is the cross-platform async I/O library node uses.
- [How libuv maps windows system errors to uv errors](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/74a664b22f2caf3ea42dcf66da638fb86aa4b81e/deps/uv/src/win/error.c#L72)
- [the node_constants.cc file has a bunch more](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/592be014b680b70ee349dda5aa5928bde28da2cd/src/node_constants.cc#L47)

Answer (score 0):

Many of the errors seem to mirror the original Linux / POSIX / C errors. See http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/errno.3.html